# Data persistence using Realm and JSON Deserialization using Jackson

Tags: android, jackson, realm

Hi I am building an Android app wherein I should save data from server to the database. I have separate DB POJOs(one for Realm and another for Jackson). I am wondering which set of POJOs should I be passing around the view layer? The direction I'm going is deserialize using jackson, then persist using realm then still use Jackson POJOs in my activities. This might be a problem when I will need to query from Realm and display the data from realm when user is in offline mode. Thank you.

Comment: Realm can deserialize json. Why not use it only?

Comment: The current implementation is already in Jackson. Is it worth it to make the shift? Also, as far as I have researched, Realm is not yet supporting serialization. Plus, I need to deserialize polymorphic types which is doable in Jackson, but sadly not in Realm @AhmedKhalaf

Comment: I don't anybody can answer the question for you. It all depends on how decoupled you want your layers. Personally I would probably either try to A) Combine everything into one set of model objects or B) Use special Jackson objects to describe the network protocol and use Realm instances as the model objects in the app i.e. send them to the UI layer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Option A is not possible since I need polymorphism which Realm does not support. However, I'm having a problem with circular dependencies when I try option B. @ChristianMelchior

Comment: Without further detail, I am not sure how to respond to that :)